# Client Recieves Data From Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

So I have a Raspberry Pi 4 and im trying to receive data from a JSON file and display it on a text element on my website. sorry if im totally wrong, it's my second day with a Raspberry Pi. I have done basic things like turn an LED on, thanks to w3schools. Im trying to make a bot hosting tool thing for myself, where it will display amount hosted on a TV

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Bots Hosted:</h1>
        <h2 id="bot-qty">0</h2>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var socket = io();
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var bot_count = document.getElementById("bot-qty");
        var times_ran = 0;
        const interval = setInterval(function() {
            socket.emit("request-count", times_ran);
            times_ran++;
        }, 20000);
    })

    socket.on('request-count', function(data) {
            document.getElementById("bot-qty").innerText = data;
    })
</script>

</html>
```

webserver.js:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(handler);
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(1337);

function handler(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            return res.end("404 Not Found");
        }
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write(data);
        return res.end();
    });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('request-count', function(data) {
        var bot_count = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("config.json", "utf8"));
        console.log(bot_count);
        socket.emit('request-count', bot_count);
    });
});
```

In console, it says

```
GET <long_url_here> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVER
```

Comment: Hi, your question is a little confusing; are you running your server and client on the RaspberryPi?

Comment: Yeah! Sorry, a bit of a newbie!

Answer (score 0):

In the `index.html` you initialize a new `Socket` instance by writing

```
var socket = io();
```

You don't provide any url, so the socket.io-client will use the default `window.location` as can be seen [here](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#io-url-options). This might be a problem, so try to set a specific url, e. g.

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
```

or (also specifying the port)

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:1337');
```

Also try to make sure that you run your `webserver.js` with `node webserver.js` prior to open the website.

Also see [this discussion](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2142) on GitHub.